# Install FEniCS to use it within Jupyter Lab

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, jupyter-lab, fenics

I’m trying to install FEniCS within Jupyter Labs (so I can import the package in my current notebooks by doing simply `import fenics`), but I’m failing miserably. First I installed it through `pip3 install fenics` as any other package, and in fact this is the output if I try to do it again:

```
DEPRECATION: Configuring installation scheme with distutils config files is deprecated and will no longer work in the near future. If you are using a Homebrew or Linuxbrew Python, please see discussion at https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/76621
Requirement already satisfied: fenics in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (2019.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: fenics-ufl<2019.2,>=2019.1.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from fenics) (2019.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: fenics-ffc<2019.2,>=2019.1.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from fenics) (2019.1.0.post0)
Requirement already satisfied: fenics-dijitso<2019.2,>=2019.1.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from fenics) (2019.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: fenics-fiat<2019.2,>=2019.1.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from fenics) (2019.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from fenics-dijitso<2019.2,>=2019.1.0->fenics) (1.22.4)
Requirement already satisfied: sympy in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from fenics-fiat<2019.2,>=2019.1.0->fenics) (1.10.1)
Requirement already satisfied: mpmath>=0.19 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from sympy->fenics-fiat<2019.2,>=2019.1.0->fenics) (1.2.1)
DEPRECATION: Configuring installation scheme with distutils config files is deprecated and will no longer work in the near future. If you are using a Homebrew or Linuxbrew Python, please see discussion at https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/76621
WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.
```

So the package is already there. However, when I import fenics in my notebooks, I get

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [1], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 import fenics

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fenics'
```

I have also tried to follow the instructions in https://fenicsproject.org/qa/13194/how-to-use-fenics-in-jupyter-by-anaconda/, which was linked by many in the context of similar questions. I did `conda create -n fenicsproject -c conda-forge python=3.5 jupyter fenics`, but when I then do `source activate fenicsproject` I get `source: no such file or directory: activate`. I tried instead `conda activate fenicsproject`, and while the environment is active I still can't import the package into my notebook.

Does anyone know a set of magic steps to be able to use FEniCS within Jupyter Labs? In case it's relevant, I'm using MacOS Monterey 12.4 with conda 4.13.0 and python 3.5.5. Many thanks!

---

UPDATE:

With the following commands I was able to create a kernel for my new environment within Jupyter:

```
conda create -n fenicsproject -c conda-forge fenics
conda activate fenicsprojec
python -m ipykernel install --user --name fenicsproject --display-name "Python (FEniCS)"
```

Now, when I do `import fenics` I get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [1], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 import fenics

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/fenicsproject/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fenics/__init__.py:7, in <module>
      1 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
      2 """Main module for FEniCS.
      3 
      4 This module is identical with the main DOLFIN module.
      5 """
----> 7 from dolfin import *

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/fenicsproject/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dolfin/__init__.py:142, in <module>
    139 from .common.timer import Timer, timed
    140 from .common.plotting import plot
--> 142 from .fem.assembling import (assemble, assemble_system, assemble_multimesh,
    143                              SystemAssembler, assemble_local)
    144 from .fem.form import Form
    145 from .fem.norms import norm, errornorm

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/fenicsproject/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dolfin/fem/assembling.py:34, in <module>
     32 import ufl
     33 import dolfin.cpp as cpp
---> 34 from dolfin.fem.form import Form
     35 from dolfin import MPI
     36 from dolfin.function.multimeshfunction import MultiMeshFunction

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/fenicsproject/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dolfin/fem/form.py:12, in <module>
     10 import ufl
     11 import dolfin.cpp as cpp
---> 12 from dolfin.jit.jit import dolfin_pc, ffc_jit
     15 class Form(cpp.fem.Form):
     16     def __init__(self, form, **kwargs):
     17 
     18         # Check form argument

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/fenicsproject/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dolfin/jit/jit.py:18, in <module>
     16     dolfin_pc = pkgconfig.parse("dolfin")
     17 else:
---> 18     raise RuntimeError("Could not find DOLFIN pkg-config file. Please make sure appropriate paths are set.")
     21 # Copied over from site-packages
     22 def mpi_jit_decorator(local_jit, *args, **kwargs):

RuntimeError: Could not find DOLFIN pkg-config file. Please make sure appropriate paths are set.
```

---

UPDATE 2:

As a clarification based on [this post](https://fenicsproject.discourse.group/t/runtimeerror-could-not-find-dolfin-pkg-config-file/1735/2), the previous error happens when I launch jupyter lab from the terminal.
In any case, the outcome of `env` is the following:

```
__CFBundleIdentifier=com.apple.Terminal
TMPDIR=/var/folders/rv/zgc93kmn1b10ngl4t5813dm80000gn/T/
XPC_FLAGS=0x0
LaunchInstanceID=0825007E-A608-4580-8509-024A76F7768E
TERM=xterm-256color
DISPLAY=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.bSgkG6FpPC/org.xquartz:0
SECURITYSESSIONID=186a3
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.cAxEHmogW6/Listeners
XPC_SERVICE_NAME=0
TERM_PROGRAM=Apple_Terminal
TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION=445
TERM_SESSION_ID=53B396DE-4AF6-4F4C-8D39-D209C6E11CED
SHELL=/bin/zsh
HOME=/Users/myuser
LOGNAME=myuser
USER=myuser
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/Users/myuser/opt/anaconda3/envs/fenicsproject/bin:/Users/myuser/opt/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/opt/X11/bin
SHLVL=1
PWD=/Users/myuser
OLDPWD=/Users/myuser
CONDA_EXE=/Users/myuser/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda
_CE_M=
_CE_CONDA=
CONDA_PYTHON_EXE=/Users/myuser/opt/anaconda3/bin/python
CONDA_SHLVL=2
CONDA_PREFIX=/Users/myuser/opt/anaconda3/envs/fenicsproject
CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV=fenicsproject
CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER=(fenicsproject) 
CONDA_PREFIX_1=/Users/myuser/opt/anaconda3
LC_CTYPE=UTF-8
_=/usr/bin/env
```

---

UPDATE 3 (SOLVED):

Contrary to the case in [this post](https://fenicsproject.discourse.group/t/runtimeerror-could-not-find-dolfin-pkg-config-file/1735/2), I could make it work by launching Jupyter Lab within the fenicsproject env in the Anaconda Navigator.

Comment: Try replacing `source activate fenicsproject` with `conda activate fenicproject`?

Comment: Hi Dominik, thanks. I did that and the environment is indeed activated. However I can still not import the package to my notebook.

Comment: For the new problem, [apparently](https://fenicsproject.discourse.group/t/runtimeerror-could-not-find-dolfin-pkg-config-file/1735/2) fenics loads a bunch of env vars when the environment is loaded. You could activate the environment, use `env` to grab their values, then replicate them before launching the actual jupyter notebook. That sounds awful, but I lack better ideas. Fenics is awesome software, but a can of worms to actually run in my experience...

Comment: @DominikStańczak could you please explain what you mean by "replicating the environment values before launching the notebook"? I will add the outcome of `env` in the original post.